# Error on iterating over array swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3

I'm trying to loop through array and get the coordinates but it's giving me an error and I can't access my array. The data is passed through a seque and if I print it shows it's working so the data is transferred correctly but can't work out why I can't iterate through the array and pull out the latitude and longitude.

This is the output in the console.

> DeliveryDestinations(NameOrBusiness: Optional("In-N-Out Burger"),
>   FirstLineAddress: Optional("550 Newhall Dr"), SecondLineAddress:
>   Optional(" United States"), CityLineAddress: Optional(" San Jose"),
>   PostcodeLineAddress: Optional(" CA  95110"), DistanceToDestination:
>   Optional(9.2807823200000001), Lat: Optional(37.350253606833043), Long:
>   Optional(-121.92182779312132))

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class DeliveryLocationsVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var addressArr = [DeliveryDestinations]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(addressArr)


navigationItem.title = "Delivery Location"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        for (theKey, theValue) in addressArr { //<-- error can't access the elements in array
            if (theKey == "Lat") {
                if let coordinates:DeliveryDestinations = theValue {
                print (coordinates)
            }
            print("Item \(theKey): \(theValue)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My array is coming from a struct below

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

struct DeliveryDestinations {
    var NameOrBusiness: String?
    var FirstLineAddress: String?
    var SecondLineAddress: String?
    var CityLineAddress: String?
    var PostcodeLineAddress: String?
    var DistanceToDestination: CLLocationDistance?
    var Lat: Double?
    var Long: Double?


    init(NameOrBusiness: String?, FirstLineAddress: String?, SecondLineAddress: String?, CityLineAddress: String?, PostCodeLineAddress: String?, DistanceToDestination: CLLocationDistance?, Lat: Double?, Long: Double? ) {
        self.NameOrBusiness = NameOrBusiness
        self.FirstLineAddress = FirstLineAddress
        self.SecondLineAddress = SecondLineAddress
        self.CityLineAddress = CityLineAddress
        self.PostcodeLineAddress = PostCodeLineAddress
        self.DistanceToDestination = DistanceToDestination
        self.Lat = Lat
        self.Long = Long

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you expect `theKey` and `theValue` to contain??

Comment: @luk2302 key will be Lat and value will be the coordinate same for long will be the key and value will be coordinate. Try to put this into array so i can populate the map with pins based on this coordinates.

Comment: Why should `theKey` be "Lat"? That makes no sense, you have an array, there is no "Lat" to be found anywhere.

Comment: @luk2302 is not this ones Lat: Optional(37.350253606833043), Long: Optional(-121.92182779312132)) key and value pairs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an Array (and not a Dictionary) so you need to do is iterate like this:

```
for object in addressArr {
    ...
    // get coordinates from object
    let lat = object.Lat
    let long = object.Long
}
```

Or if you need index of a table row as well you can do:

```
for (i, object) in addressArr.enumerated() {
    ...
    // get coordinates from object
    let lat = object.Lat
    let long = object.Long
    print ("Destination at index \(i) has coordinate: (\(lat), \(long))")
}
```

How did I know it was a Array?

Notation in the code

```
 var addressArr = [DeliveryDestinations]()
```

allways mean, that this is an array of objects DeliveryDestinations.
When you print it out, you get print of the object in the array. 
In your case, this object has a "dictionary like" description, so the print function print it like this.

In every object, with `description` function you can specify how the text would look like when you print on object (or array of those objects)

Comment: Zedravec This worked perfectly for me both solutions are perfect. One question is where i messed up how did you know that this was an array and not dictionary because here i got confused. Lat: Optional(37.350253606833043), Long: Optional(-121.92182779312132)) is this not a key-value pair?

Comment: @QuickSilver `var addressArr = [DeliveryDestinations]()`, that is an array, period. No matter what it contains and how those things decide to convert itself to a string, it will remain an array.

Comment: @luk2302 Thnks for explaining that sorry I'm fairly new to this so I'm still learning. Much appreciate your help guys.